# How to make t:collapsiblePanel to work in chrome and IE10

Tags: javascript

I am using the JSP not JSF system. My t:collapsiblePanel is working perfect in IE7 and IE8, but in chrome it does not collapse, and i dont get any error message

```
 <htm:table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
     <t:dataList var="benefit" value="#{benGroup.benefitMemberGroupsBeans}" layout="simple">
     <t:collapsiblePanel value="#{benefit.collapsed}" var="isCollapsed"  >
     <f:facet name="header">
    <htm:tr styleClass="benefits_table_core_benefit">
      <t:headerLink onclick="if (validateQuoteBenefits('')) return false;" immediate="true">
                                                <htm:td  colspan="#{quoteBenefitsBean.totalNoOfColumns}" style="width:#{155+100*quoteBenefitsBean.noOfMemberGroups };  border-left: 1px solid black; border-top: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">                                              <h:panelGroup rendered="#{isCollapsed}">
```